# All of the "more results" and navigation links lead to a 404 error

Tags: navigation, 404-error

This is really starting to look like something that will never get fixed!
I've tried EVERYTHING I found on the internet and it doesn't work.

The navigations on the pages (more results, 1,2,3 etc.) all fail after the first page.
The first page of search results, blog posts, categories and everything works correctly but after that it all goes to a 404 error. It detects the right number of posts to show per page correctly but then fails to show it in the next page.

I've since tried:

-Disabling all plugins

-Removing htaccess file and letting Wordpress make another one by clicking Save Changes in the Permalink settings

-Trying all kinds of permalink structures, e.g. going back to the default.

-Changing the last blog posts and RSS entries setting in Reading settings page to any number that was suggested on forums and everywhere

-Checking whether it's my hosting that has the problem, which turned out the same theme I'm using now is being used by somebody else on the very same reseller account by my friend and the second pages work on his!

-Making changes to the rewrite.php file

NONE of these worked. I'm running out of ideas, so please if anyone has any idea why this is happening let me know. I've spent countless hours trying to fix this but it just keeps on showing the 404 page.

Current Permalink structure is:

```
 /%postname%/
```

.htaccess content:

```
# -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName daycagayrimenkul.com
AuthUserFile /home/daycagay/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/daycagay/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Website's address is: http://www.daycagayrimenkul.com/

Example page with the problem:

http://www.daycagayrimenkul.com/?s=Search...&sale_type=all&subtype=all&subcom=all&property_types=96&location_names=0&locadu=0&price_min=&price_max=&size_min=&size_max=&no_beds=all&no_baths=all&no_garages=all&no_apfloors=all&floorlocated=all&devtype=all&floorratio=all&heighter=all&deed=all&agreement=all&buildfloor=all&levelfloor=all&heating=all&usage=all&mortgage=all&historical=all&swap=all&property-search-submit=search

Notice that the " More Results »" link at the bottom goes to a 404 page, although it does have results to show.

Please, any kind of input or help is appreciated. Thanks

Edit:

I just tested my template files (copied everything and put it on a new installation) and they worked. However, when I imported all my data from my old installation, that's when the second pages started to crash again. So I've isolated the problem to be in the data which Wordpress exports, but sadly when I deleted all my posts one by one after importing, to see which one's the culprit, none of them were! Deleted all categories and posts and still the second pages cease to work after importing the data.

I can't really write everything from scratch (the posts etc.) because there's about 1,500 posts/pages/categories. Is there any way to have a debug mode to find out where the data is failing?

Comment: what are the contents of the template file that renders that page?

Comment: I would post all the template files if you want but I just tested my template files (copied everything and put it on a new installation) and they worked. However, when I imported all my data from my old installation, that's when the second pages started to crash again. 

So I've isolated the problem to be in the data which Wordpress exports, but sadly when I deleted all my posts one by one after importing, to see which one's the culprit, none of them were! Deleted all categories and posts and still the second pages cease to work after importing the data.

Comment: I can't really write everything from scratch (the posts etc.) because there's about 1,500 posts/pages/categories. Is there any way to have a debug mode to find out where the data is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the theme, upgrading to 3.4.2 from 3.3.1 caused this.